# Select rows having > 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, select, decimal

How to select rows having value more than 2 decimal places?

For example we have these values:

```
3.14
5.999
9.555
8.55
```

And i want to select these values only:

```
5.999
9.555
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sorry, i've found the answer already:

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTR(`column`,INSTR(`column`,"."))) >3

Comment: or you could try substring_index instead of just substr: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 11):

You can use `_` as a single-character wildcard with `LIKE`

```
LIKE '%.___'
```